# need password and confirm password fields in user/register page drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am new to drupal. I want the fields(password, confirm password, roles) from admin/people/create to user/register page.

User can create their account with particular role. How can I achieve that when the user register their account.

Answer (score 1):

By help of this code snippets _form();

The Drupal Form API `password_confirm` element

```
$form['pass_fields'] = array(

  '#type' => 'password_confirm' ,

  '#description' => t('Enter the same password in both fields'),

  '#size' => 32,

  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

To check or auto save user role in _form();:

```
$role = 'user-role';

array( 'roles' => $roles );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this module https://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole

Also if you unchecked option Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account. under Home » Administration » Configuration » People

Then you get password and confirm password fields in user registration form.

Answer (score 0):

I created user-register-form.tpl.php with the following code.

```
<?php print render($form['account']); ?>
<?php print render($form['form_build_id']); ?>
<?php print render($form['form_id']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['actions']); ?>
```

I unchecked require e-mail verification link. Using profile2_regpath module i checked the role. It is for when the user creates their accounts the role will automatically assign to the user.